# Xcode 9.4 : Error generating code coverage

Tags: ios, swift4, code-coverage, xcode9.4

I'm running all test cases of project (cmd + U) then all of sudden this error message pops-up with no reason. I'm using Xcode 9.4.

[image: Screenshot 1]

Any fix?

Comment: any logs in console about error ?

Comment: @Ramesh.G : Nothing on console and that is wondering part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is is possible you are running on device and it is locked?

The same thing just happened for me ("Error Generating Code Coverage" when trying to run all tests) and then I realized that Xcode was trying to build to my phone, which was locked. It ran ok on my phone after I unlocked it (and fine on the simulator as well).

Comment: Thanks for this. While the device I was trying to deploy to was definitely unlocked, I also had another iPhone plugged in that was. Disconnecting that iPhone made the error go away for me.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem and was able to solve it by running on a simulator rather than on my iPhone. If that doesn't work for you, look in the Report navigator (look for this button: [image: report navigator toolbar button, looks like a speech bubble] ) I had a failing Build Log in there with a message like this:

> Test target *MyAppTests* encountered an error (Unable to connect to
>   test manager on *xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx* If you
>   believe this error represents a bug, please attach the log file at
>   /var/folders/…*filename.log*)

If you have a message like that, take a look at the log file… it's what made me realise it was trying to connect to my iPhone.

Answer (score -2):

Just restart your device. This simple way fix my problem.